# Jmeter Regular Expression

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I am struggling find solution to Jmtere dynamic input value which return one matched value but with the sub strings.

```
</script></span><input type="hidden" name="j_id_s_1_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:1" value="07JgPgLP3e1jdtHd6s1UxDoKEaCU362MYbfU48r9paGrBDfo" autocomplete="off" /></form>
```

i try to get "07JgPgLP3e1jdtHd6s1UxDoKEaCU362MYbfU48r9paGrBDfo" this value. i reuslar expression:

```
j_id_s_1_SUBMIT" value="(.+)"
```

referencename: view

It returns:

```
Match count: 1
Match[1][0]=j_id_s_1_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:1" value="07JgPgLP3e1jdtHd6s1UxDoKEaCU362MYbfU48r9paGrBDfo" autocomplete="off"
Match[1][1]=1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:1" value="07JgPgLP3e1jdtHd6s1UxDoKEaCU362MYbfU48r9paGrBDfo" autocomplete="off
```

i tried `${__substring(${view}, 101, 149)}` , my script still fail. Any other solutions? 
Thanks

Comment: Please revisit your question and use the edit button to highlight the code. As of now, it remains unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), a minor markup change, adding or replacing an attribute, rendering a part of tag on the next line, whatever and your test is ruined.

You have:

- [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), relevant XPath query will be as simple as `//input[@name='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value`
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor), selection will be `input[name=javax.faces.ViewState]`, use `value` as the attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
name="j_id_s_1_SUBMIT"\svalue="(.+?)"\s/>
```

if you don't tell it to stop after first match (which is `?` after `.+`), it's gonna take as broad match, as possible - and that's what happened.

**PS** But that's following your expression, while by it you'll get `1`, not that token you'd needed.

So, to get your stuff, you'd better do

```
id="j_id__v_0:javax\.faces\.ViewState:1"\svalue="(.+?)"\sautocomplete
```

**PPS** Your html seem to be well-formed, why not use XPath extractor then? You'd not be dependent on the attributes order and/or overall structure of HTML in your response then.

**PPPS** And here's even better trick right from official JMeter doc:

> Note: although the above expression works, it's more efficient to use
>   the following expression:  name="file" value="([^"]+)"> where [^"] -
>   means match anything except " In this case, the matching engine can
>   stop looking as soon as it sees the first ", whereas in the previous
>   case the engine has to check that it has found "> rather than say " >.

RTFM is still trendy, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Thanks. Rally appreciated !

Comment: Thanks. Rally appreciated ! now it gives me right value, I try to update address in my application, and submit, I put the viewstate value, but it still throws 500 error, should I use other value as well? when I use blazemeter record, it gives me like this value   ViewSate=4bAuxA6j/nZjdtHd6s1UxM75jfae6h2OwGJvRZZXY8I7wK1Q   thanks, for the answer.